React behaves in a bizarre way
I'm trying to make this memory card game.
It works fine but the attempts counter at the bottom behvaes in a bizarre way. In facts it sometimes increases by 1, some other times by 2.
why does that happen?
import { useState } from 'react';
import Button from "./Button";

const possibleElements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

function randomNumber() {
    const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleElements.length);
    const randomNumber = possibleElements[randIndex];
    possibleElements.splice(randIndex, 1);
    return randomNumber;
}

const gameTable = [
    [randomNumber(), randomNumber(), randomNumber(), randomNumber()],
    [randomNumber(), randomNumber(), randomNumber(), randomNumber()],
    [randomNumber(), randomNumber(), randomNumber(), randomNumber()],
    [randomNumber(), randomNumber(), randomNumber(), randomNumber()]
];

export default function GameBoard() {
    const [selection, setSelection] = useState([]);
    const [coupledElements, setCoupledElements] = useState([]);
    const [isEnabled, setIseEnabled] = useState(true);
    const [attempts, setAttempts] = useState(0);

    function sortCoupledElements(selection) {
        if (selection[0].value === selection[1].value) {
            setCoupledElements((prevCoupledElements) => {
                const newCoupledElements = [...prevCoupledElements, selection[0].index, selection[1].index];
                return newCoupledElements;
            })
        }
    }

    function whenClicked(index, value) {
        setSelection((prevSelection) => {
            const newSelection = [...prevSelection, { index, value }];

            if (newSelection.length === 2) {
                setAttempts((prevAttempts) => (prevAttempts + 1));
                setIseEnabled(false);
                sortCoupledElements(newSelection);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setSelection([]);
                    setIseEnabled(true);
                }, 1000);
            }
            return newSelection;
        })
    }

    return (
        <main>
            <div className="game-board">
                <ol className="row">
                    {gameTable.map((row, rowIndex) => (
                        <li key={rowIndex}>
                            <ol className="column">
                                {row.map((value, colIndex) => {
                                    const elementIndex = rowIndex * 4 + colIndex
                                    return (
                                        <li key={colIndex}>
                                            <Button
                                                isSelected={selection.some((element) => (element.index === elementIndex))}
                                                ifClicked={whenClicked}
                                                isCoupled={coupledElements.includes(elementIndex)}
                                                isEnabled={isEnabled}
                                                index={elementIndex}
                                                value={value} />
                                        </li>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div id="attempts">
                <h3>{attempts} attempts!</h3>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}

Thank you in advance!
I thought it might be cause by the fact setAttempts rerender the component inside setSelection rerender.
The problem is that it must be called when selection.length is 2.
I tried to do it with a function:
function increaseAttempts() {
    setAttempts((prevAttempts) => (prevAttempts +1))
}

and call this function inside the setSelection call after the if (newSelection.length ===2) statement but in that case another bizarre thing happened, i.e. no button kepts its isSelected prop equal to true ever.

Welcome to SO! As the issue might be related to your custom Button Component, it would be worth sharing its code as well. Please make sure to provide a [mcve].

You should not update a variable's state inside the update function of another state variable. Use useEffect hook to perform such task adding the other variable as its dependency.
function whenClicked(index, value) {
        setSelection((prevSelection) => {
            const newSelection = [...prevSelection, { index, value }];

            // do not update any other state here
            return newSelection;
        })
    }

useEffect(()=>{
   if (selection.length === 2) {
                setAttempts((prevAttempts) => (prevAttempts + 1));
                setIseEnabled(false);
                sortCoupledElements(newSelection);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setSelection([]);
                    setIseEnabled(true);
                }, 1000);
            }
}, [selection.length])


Thank you for your reply. I'm currently doing a React course and I've not covered useEffect yet. Thisis a practice project I started coding, taking a pause from the course just to put together what I've learned. So that's the reason then. Thank you very much!
